# core service creation of nested keywords

Tags: core-service, powershell, keyword

I'm trying to create keyword using core service API through PowerShell. I can do this for keywords at top-level under a category

```
$keyword = [Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.KeywordData]$client.GetDefaultData($itemTypeKeyword, $ParentWebdavUrl, $readoptions)
$keyword.Title = $Value
$keyword.Key = $Key
$keyword.Description = $Description
```

however, if I try to use the GetDefaultData when the $ParentWebdavUrl is a keyword instead of a category, it fails (specifically: Exception calling "GetDefaultData" with "3" argument(s): "Unexpected item type: Keyword."). So, I'm trying to do this, below, but can't seem to get the ParentKeywords to work. I've tried many permutations of creating the $parentLinks object to no avail.

```
$keyword = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.KeywordData
$keyword.Title = $Value
$keyword.Key = $Key
$keyword.Description = $Description
$parentLink = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToKeywordData
$parentLink.IdRef = $parent.Id
$parentLinks = [Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToKeywordData[]]([Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToKeywordData]$parentLink)
$keyword.ParentKeywords = $parentLinks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent item of your keyword remains the Category. You should set `ParentKeywords` property and pass your parent keyword there.

```
#here's what I was missing... need to set LocationInfo
$locInfo = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LocationInfo
$locInfo.OrganizationalItem = $parent.LocationInfo.OrganizationalItem
$locInfo.ContextRepository = $parent.LocationInfo.ContextRepository
$locInfo.Path = $parent.LocationInfo.Path
#apparently you don't have to set webdav url on it
#$locInfo.WebDavUrl = Get-EncodedWebdavUrl -WebdavUrl ($locInfo.Path + "\" + $Value + ".tkw")
#now associate to the keyword
$keyword.LocationInfo = $locInfo
```

Comment: isn't that what I'm doing? I tested by creating a sub-keyword, doing ParentKeywords on it and inspecting the IdRef, which is the same value I'm setting in my $parentLink.IdRef = $parent.Id statement above. but the $parentLinks object doesn't seem to be constructed properly into an IEnumerable object that ParentKeywords method is expecting

Comment: If the code sample is everything you pass than you need to set `LocationInfo.OrganizationalItem` as well.

Comment: that's what I was missing!! awesome. thanks. problem solved! edited your answer to include the code I was missing.